# Can loose metal piece cause unclean shutdown?

Tags: crash, hardware-failure

A laptop I administer has recently been suffering from random unclean shutdowns when it is moved around. Not every time, perhaps once every 3-5 days, but still annoying. I finally got around to taking a look at it, and I noticed a rattling sound when it was moved. I opened the RAM/Wifi card panel and found a very small piece of metal, even smaller than a penny.

[image]

Could this cause these random shutdowns?

I checked the Windows event viewer, which had [this error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504) recorded, 16 times. I took some screenshots of the error, viewable [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaUbH.jpg). The laptop is a Dell Inspiron running Windows 7 and is about 3 years old.

Comment: Has the issue reoccurred since you removed the piece?

Comment: This is a ground contact which should have stayed clipped on an internal metallic border. This is the sign of a poor quality assembly if this laptop was never opened before these spurious crashes.

Comment: @CharlieRB, no, but like I said it occurs infrequently, and I just removed the piece last night. Crossing my fingers...

Answer (score 5):

It absolutely could. It could short connections inside the laptop, causing crashes, shutdowns, and potentially even a fire or permanent damage.

Comment: yup, i've had similar once when i lost a screw behind a motherboard.

Comment: It could also cause electric shocks to users.